How to transpose and modify a pandas dataframe based on column values
I have a set of data like below:
name A B C
foo  1 0 0
bar  0 1 0 
coo  0 0 1

That I am trying to alter to look like the table below:
   name 
A  foo
B  bar
C  coo

I've done research but have gotten no luck. I'm not sure if it is possible within python. Do I need to manually change this table to get the result I am looking for?

Don't forget to upvote answers you find useful and accept the best one :)

So I figured out a solution to my problem and it turns out that what I was asking here had sent me in the wrong direction, however I appreciate everyone taking the time and explaining their various processes! Definitely learned new things about pandas of the course of the last few days.

If there is a single 1 in every row, the following method is the simplest.
out = df.set_index('name').idxmax()

out
A    foo
B    bar
C    coo
dtype: object

Example
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'coo'], 
        'A': [1, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 1, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  name  A  B  C
0  foo  1  0  0
1  bar  0  1  0
2  coo  0  0  1


This looks like dummies, though transposed and not the same format Pandas produces. We can use .from_dummies() with a few additional steps.
df.set_index('name').transpose().pipe(
    lambda d: (
        pd.from_dummies(d)
        .set_axis([d.columns.name], axis=1)  # "name"

        # Workaround for Pandas bug GH 54300, fixed in Pandas 2.1.0.
        .set_axis(d.index)  # A, B, C
    )
)

  name
A  foo
B  bar
C  coo

This assumes each row contains one 1.
Setup for reference
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'coo'],
    'A': [1, 0, 0],
    'B': [0, 1, 0],
    'C': [0, 0, 1]})


Pandas.melt() unpivots a DataFrame from wide format to long format.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "name": ["foo", "bar", "coo"],
    "A": [1, 0, 0],
    "B": [0, 1, 0],
    "C": [0, 0, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
melted = df.melt(id_vars="name", var_name="category", value_name="value")
print(melted)

output:
   name category  value
0  foo        A      1
1  bar        A      0
2  coo        A      0
3  foo        B      0
4  bar        B      1
5  coo        B      0
6  foo        C      0
7  bar        C      0
8  coo        C      1

next:
filtered = melted[melted["value"] == 1]
result = filtered[["category", "name"]]
print(result)

output:
   category name
0        A  foo
4        B  bar
8        C  coo


assuming the data is already in a dataframe df as you describe, try using a list comprehension:
result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            df["name"][i]
            for col in ["A", "B", "C"]
            for i in range(len(df))
            if df[col][i] == 1
        ]
    },
    index=["A", "B", "C"],
)


While @wjandrea has already proposed a solution using the from_dummies method, I believe the following approach, also based on from_dummies, is more concise and straightforward:
(pd.from_dummies(df.set_index('name'))
 .reset_index().set_index('').rename_axis(None))

Output:
  name
A  foo
B  bar
C  coo


I considered something like this, but to me it doesn't make sense given the structure of the data. Hard to say though with such a small sample.
